# how to control directory permissions with matlab's mkdir command?

Tags: matlab, file-permissions, mkdir

matlab's `mkdir` command seems to always set permissions 755, and the function doesn't seem to accept any options to change this.

It doesn't even seem to respect umask (umask of 2 corresponds to permissions 775 or rwxrwxr-x).

```
>> !umask
2
>> mkdir /tmp/test
>> ls -l /tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  2 username  groupname          6 Mar 30 10:51 test/
```

If I just create one directory, then using `fileattrib` after the fact is relatively trivial, but if I create a sub-directory e.g. `/tmp/test1/test2` then matlab's mkdir creates all non-existent parent directories by default. (As if the `-p` flag had been set for the unix version of mkdir.) If I only want to set the permissions on the new directories, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to tell which parts of the tree are new and which are old.

For the record, I'm using R2014b on linux.

Comment: I wish there is a `sudo` in Matlab 2016b.

Comment: can't you just directly use the UNIX command: `>> !mkdir -p /tmp/test1/test2`?

Comment: @Amro yes, that's a good idea. I might do it that way. Two reasons not to: 1) I assume that would break portability to windows 2) matlab *should* have a way to make this work

Comment: I don't think the `umask` notion maps to Windows anyway.. What you're doing is not portable to begin with.

Comment: I guess not. I think windows mkdir inherits the permissions of the parent directory. Maybe matlab uses this convention across all platforms?

Comment: Maybe a bit messy but it is possible to set file attributes afterwards at least http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileattrib.html. I do not know any way to set attributes with Matlabs `mkdir`. You can of course write function with better portability by using `ispc, ismac` and `isunix` inside some more portable function. Then each system can use their own system commands in the function.

Comment: The Windows security model is not comparable to that of POSIX-like systems. For example there is no exact equivalent to group/other permissions, and `fileattrib` will actually return NaN for these fields on Windows... Like I said, `umask`, `chmod` and the like are not portable.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13554/1177. If you're interested you can also see how Cygwin tackles this issue: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html

Answer (score -1):

Recent version of `Maltlab` can modify permission in an OS transparent way using the `fileattrib` command.

Comment: At the moment this doesn't add anything to the comments given by Amro. Please expand to make this a valid answer. (e.g. syntax to use fileattrib, how it deals with recursively made directories etc.)

Comment: @craq Well this would help, but I think as-is this adds to the discussion because this is a new interface that wasn't present before. Note the discussion where people claim its not possible to do. Well they are now wrong.